# how do we use watch as a callback in react-hook form(v6)?

Tags: react-hook-form

The docs for v6 of react hook form say something like -

```
// Callback version of watch.  It's your responsibility to unsubscribe when done.
React.useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = watch((value, { name, type }) => console.log(value, name, type));
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [watch]);
```

Can someone give me some examples of this implementation?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do. But if you want to watch a specific value, you can do like this:

```
const value = watch('value'); // value is the name of the input from your form
console.log(value); // No need for useEffect, this will re-render whenever value is changed
```

Comment: No, you still need useEffect() because the code we be execute at every re valuate for the component